# How to get JSON values by index number using PostgerSQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have this sample data:

```
   ID          Name
    1     {'a':'content1'}
    1     {'b':'content1'}
    1     {'c':'content2'}
    1     {'d':'content2'}
    1     {'e':'content3'}
    1     {'f':'content3'}
    2     ['content4']
    2     ['content4']
    2     ['content5']
    2     ['content5']
```

with

ID   : INT

Name : JSON

I want to have this result

```
   ID       Name
    1     content1
    1     content1
    1     content2
    1     content2
    1     content3
    1     content3
    2     content4
    2     content4
    2     content5
    2     content5
```

Usually, when dealing with `JSON`, I always use `::JSON ->> 'key'`

but, when `ID` =  1 then `key` of name column change greatly. So I wonder if there is any way to get value (content) without specificly call the key of JSON values.

I literally dont know how to solve this problem to provide my try.

p/s: postgreSQL only please

VERSION: PostgreSQL 11.4 (Debian 11.4-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit

Comment: What if your JSON objects contain more than one key or if the arrays contain more than one element?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, well currently working on Superset, data was uploaded to Superset so cant tell which version it is,  data was built by several developers. And yes some have more than 1 key. Any suggestion or solution ?

Comment: Yes first one only, I already included version in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to deal with multiple keys/array elements, you can apply a limit clause when extracting the keys/elements.

```
select t.id, o.content
from test t
  cross join lateral (
    (
      select content
      from jsonb_each_text(t.name) as e(key,content)
      where jsonb_typeof(t.name) = 'object'
      limit 1
    )
    union all
    (
      select *
      from jsonb_array_elements_text(t.name)
      where jsonb_typeof(t.name) = 'array'
      limit 1
    )
  ) o ;
```

Note that the `limit` will pick an arbitrary element, it's not guaranteed that it's the "first" one - but highly likely.

To pick an element by index, you could use:

```
select t.id, o.content
from test t
  cross join lateral (
    select e.content
    from jsonb_each_text(t.name) with ordinality as e(key,content,idx)
    where jsonb_typeof(t.name) = 'object'
      and e.idx = 1
    union all
    select e.element
    from jsonb_array_elements_text(t.name)  with ordinality as e(element,idx)
    where jsonb_typeof(t.name) = 'array'
     and e.idx = 1
  ) o ;
```

If your `name` column is defined as `json` (rather than `jsonb` which it should be), then you need to use the corresponding `json_xxx` function (not `jsonb_xxx`)

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9d54cb512a5d411a3b2d46ab38a7e7b0)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `json_typeof()` to determine what to use in a lateral join to either `json_each_text()` for `object` values or `json_array_elements_text()` for `array` values and then `union` the results.

```
select o.id, e.v as name
  from j_by_index o
       cross join lateral json_each_text(o.name) as e(k,v)
 where json_typeof(o.name) = 'object'
union all
select a.id, e.v
  from j_by_index a
       cross join lateral json_array_elements_text(a.name) as e(v)
 where json_typeof(a.name) = 'array';

┌────┬──────────┐
│ id │   name   │
├────┼──────────┤
│  1 │ content1 │
│  1 │ content1 │
│  1 │ content2 │
│  1 │ content2 │
│  1 │ content3 │
│  1 │ content3 │
│  2 │ content4 │
│  2 │ content4 │
│  2 │ content5 │
│  2 │ content5 │
└────┴──────────┘
(10 rows)
```